# Unable to update a property of a child element in Mongo using golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I am working on a mongo query in golang using mgo to update a child element property

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b64a0d3931653c36bcaf0b5"),
        "quantity" : 2,
        "product" : "ABC",   
        "children" : [ 
            {     "jiraId":"100"      
                "isBlocked" : true,
                "blockedMessage" : "Error occurred: TRACEID",
                "serialNo" : "abc123",
                "token" : "",            
            }
        ]
    }
```

The query I am using in below

```
Update(repository.MongoSpec{Selector: bson.M{"children": bson.M{"$elemMatch": bson.M{"jid": "100"}}}, Query: bson.M{"children": bson.M{"$set": fields}}})
```

Below is the update function

```
    s := spec.(MongoSpec).Selector
q := spec.(MongoSpec).Query
err := session.
    DB(repo.config.databaseName).
    C(repo.collectionName).
    Update(s, q)
```

MongoSpec struct

```
  type MongoSpec struct {
        Selector interface{}
        Query    interface{}
    }
```

The above query throws an error as below

```
The dollar ($) prefixed field '$set' in 'children.$set' is not valid for storage.
```

May I know what is wrong with the query.

Answer (score 2):

> Update(repository.MongoSpec{Selector: bson.M{"children": bson.M{"$elemMatch": bson.M{"jid": "100"}}}, Query: bson.M{"children": bson.M{"$set": fields}}})

If you specify only a single query condition in the [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) expression, you do not need to use `$elemMatch`. Just use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) to access the elements of an array or embedded document. For example in [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) shell:

```
db.collection.update(
      {"children.jid": "100"}, 
      {"$set":{"children.$.field":"foobar"}})
```

Notice that the update operator [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) is specified first before any fields. See also [Set Fields in Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents).

Also, please note the additional `$` between the array field `children` and `field`. This is a [positional $ operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) to identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying with position of the element in the array. For example, if you have two elements in `children` only apply the update operator to the element matching `jid="100"`.

Similarly using `mgo.v2`, you can specify:

```
err = c.Update(
         bson.M{"children.jid":"100"}, 
         bson.M{"$set":bson.M{"children.$.field":"foobar"}}
      )
```

Worth mentioning that `mgo.v2` has been discontinued, if you're starting a new project use [mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) to support MongoDB v3.2 and above.

Comment: `mgo.v2` has been discontinued, but it lives on and is improved in [github.com/globalsign/mgo](https://github.com/globalsign/mgo).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not usign correctly $set, check this example and adapt it to your language:

```
getCollection('collectionName').findOneAndUpdate(
   {"children.jiraId":100}, //Search the subdocument
   {$set:{"children.$.isBloqued":false}}}, //update the subdocument
)
```